# TYPO3 password protect a single Page

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x, typo3-extensions

I have a scenario in which I need to password protect a single page in typo3. No front-end user required Just a password protection is enough.

Regards,
Gogul

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems regarding the solution by using a `.htaccess`. It will fail at least in the following cases:

- Call the page with the alternative url `index.php?id=<pageid>`
- If an editor changes the page title, the URL will change as well and you loose the protection.

Using felogin is really simple as it is a core extension and you don't need any registration. Further advantages are:

- It is secure. Passwords are transferred using RSA protection if you don't yet use https
- You can add a login box on the same page and hide it if someobody logs in
- Any editor can create users and change passwords

Comment: yep I used felogin for this implementation

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this kind of feature is not part of typo3 core system.

Easiest way is probably using a `.htaccess` file to password protect a single page.

Example configuration:

```
<FilesMatch "secret-area.html">
  AuthName "The text the user sees when login in"
  AuthType Basic
  AuthUserFile /file/to/htaccess/.htpasswd
  require valid-user
</FilesMatch>
```

The actual user information is stored in the above mentioned file `.htpasswd`. To create a vaild `.htpasswd` file you can use a online generator like http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/

For a detailed explanationb have a look at http://support.hostgator.com/articles/cpanel/how-to-password-protect-one-file

Another possibility is using the extension `password` but it's quite old and probably needs to be adopted to be used with a current TYPO3 version: https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/password

Comment: Yes I too had this option in mind. But had a second thought and implemented FeLogin itself. Thanks for your Support.